# Sending user-to-user push-notifications

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, push-notification

How i can send push-notifications (I'm using Parse.com for this) from my mobile to other mobile without server? Something like user-to-user push. It's really?

Answer (score 0):

Not really possible. Push is a bit more involved than that, but you can just use Google Cloud Messaging for your push notifications, which is preferred anyway.

Here's a good tutorial: https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications